# Managing Apache HTTP Server via Java code

Tags: java, apache

Does anyone know of a library that would allow me to tweak [Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/) parameters (such as Max Keep Alive or Max Clients) programmatically from withing Java code, without having to resort to parsing and modifing the configuration file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not until i know, you need to do it from scratch parsing the file, or build a script that do it with an easy 'sed' line and call to it from java.